# How to register a PolymerExpression filter inside a custom element, in Polymer.dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

How do I register a PolymerExpression filter inside a custom element? I am using Polymer.dart.

I want to use this:

```
<div>Uppercase: {{bob.fullName | uppercase}}</div>
```

inside the template of my custom element. Where do I register `uppercase` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `PolymerElement`, override `instanceTemplate`:

```dart
  DocumentFragment instanceTemplate(Element template) =>
      template.createInstance(this,
          new PolymerExpressions(globals: {
            'uppercase': (String input) => input.toUpperCase()
          }));
```

Notice you have to create an instance of `PolymerExpressions` and register the filter. Then you must call `template.createInstance`

Comment: If you are interested in an easier way, you may want to star: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13480

Answer (score 3):

I tried Seth answer and the expressions themselves are working but somehow I am losing events on my component.
My `on-click` event was not working anymore when I was using:

```dart
  DocumentFragment instanceTemplate(Element template) =>
      template.createInstance(this,
          new PolymerExpressions(globals: {
            'uppercase': (String input) => input.toUpperCase()
  }));
```

I also tried the solution proposed on the polymer expressions page but the binding delegate is apparently missing. Because of a new version maybe?

Anyway, after looking into the code I found another way to have expressions and also to keep events working.

```dart
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {

  MainElement.created() : super.created();

  @override
  BindingDelegate syntax = new MyPolymerExpressions();
}

class MyPolymerExpressions extends PolymerExpressions {

  MyPolymerExpressions(): super(globals: {
      'uppercase': (String input) => input.toUpperCase()
  });

  @override
  prepareBinding(String path, name, node) => Polymer.prepareBinding(path, name, node, super.prepareBinding);
}
```

I noticed that events are working the `prepareBinding` method is overrided.

If anyone has a better way to do it or some thoughts about this, I am quite interested!

Answer (score 1):

From a [discussion on the dart-misc](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/pcM8O7fg0mU/discussion), the polymer expressions is looking for a return that accepts a single argument. So to reproduce the `toFixed` [example of parameters](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#filter-parameters) you need to return a function from the filter:

```dart
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {

  MainElement.created() : super.created();

  String toFixed(int digits) => (num n) => n.toStringAsFixed(digits);
}
```

Also, from the [`polymer_expressions` package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_expressions), you no longer need to do a custom binding/delegate to use the expression filter: "Polymer Expressions are now the default syntax for  custom elements." It appears you can just add the function directory to your element and use it as a filter.

Comment: See also Eric Taix answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379167 I didn't realize that he actually did it that way.